# jquery mobile footer bar is not fixed while page is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile and while page is loading the footer bar appeared for a fraction of second. I'm consuming JSON for listing. While list is appeared the footer bar will disappeared. And when it is scrolling it wil appear in correct position after that it will works well plz help me to resolve this .....

here is my footer code

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  align="justify" style="margin:auto;position:relative" data-theme="c" >
   <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul class="tabs-ul" >
          <li>
              <div align="justify">
                  <a href="#" id="topup"  data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn"   data-iconpos="top" >TOP UP</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li >
              <a href="#" class="ui-btn"  data-icon="refresh"  data-iconpos="top">CREDIT</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" class="ui-btn" id="about"  data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="top">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this js code snippet as soon as you finish consuming the JSON

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.show(true);
```